# Google Sheets - Sum of every nth row displayed in the adjacent column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am making a spreadsheet to manage my spending on food at work. At the moment, I am getting the total of every week in the last column, but I would also like to total the spending for the month, [something like this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPJG4.png) but neater and so I can just drag down the rows instead of manually type it every 4 rows.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to manage - its all a question of which cell(s) you choose to select and drag. Don't just click and drag the cell with the formula; select the three blank cells as well - then drag four cells down the column. This will give a formula in every fourth row.

---

The SUM formula calculates the costs for the first 4 week period. All Good.

Now, if you select this cell and simply drag it down, then every cell will get a copy of that formula. not good.
[image: select every cell]

---

But... if you select the first four rows of the first month (*including the blank weeks 1, 2 and 3*). Like this
[image: Select four cells]

---

and then drag all four cells down the column, then only every fourth cell will have a formula and the preceding three cells will be blank.
[image: click and drag four rows]